# Add php code in Gantry 5 template header

Tags: joomla

I am using Gantry 5 template and I want to add php code in the header. I set some variables using php and access them in the script tag. For example

```
<?php
    $id = $user->id;
    $name = $user->username;
?>
<script>
    var id = '<?php echo $id; ?>';
    var name = '<?php echo $name; ?>';
</script>
```

I want to add the above code in head of Gantry 5 template. In we just add the code in index.php but this mechanism is different in Gantry 5. How this code can be added?

Comment: To access the $user object you have to instantiate the user class by using this $user = JFactory::getUser(); After that you can access the user object.

Comment: @AmitRay I have used $user = JFactory::getUser(); in my actual code. I just posted it as an example.

Comment: That is why half the code is dangerous and will unnecessarily consume more time. We have to start from basic and then move to advanced troubleshooting. If you give the full code you will get a better reply. If stackoverflow character limit is over you can use pastebin.com. Check what stackoverflow recommends to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask